# covariance of a function of Wiener processes

Tags: calculus, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Consider two independent Wiener processes, $W_1$ and $W_2$. The covariance of certain functions of Wiener processes is simple, for example $$\text{cov}\Big(W_1(r)-\int_0^1W_1(r)dr,W_1(s)-\int_0^1W_1(r)dr\Big)=\min(s,t)+st.$$ Now consider $$Z(r)=W_1(r)-\frac{\int_0^1W_1(s)W_2(s)ds}{\int_0^1W_2^2(s)ds}W_2(r)$$
which is the residuals of regressing $W_1$ on $W_2$.

Is there any way to write down the covariance of $Z$? How could we neatly approach this problem, since directly looking at the covariance results in long calculations involving a lot of functions without closed forms.

Maybe this falls into some class of processes which makes the calculations simple ...

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm confused by your definition of $Z(r)$.  In general, if you are regressing $Y = aX + b + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is your residual then $a = \frac{Cov(Y,X)}{Var(X)}$ but above you have the coefficient being a random variable.

Comment: Let's regress $W_1$ on $W_2$, the regression coefficient turns out to be $$a=\frac{\int_0^1W_1(s)W_2(s)ds}{\int_0^1W_2^2(s)ds}$$ hence the residuals are $Z(r)=W_1(r)-aW_2(r)$.

Comment: @Math-fund   Unless I misunderstand what you mean by regress $W_1$ on $W_2$ I don't think that is right.  From my explanation above the regression you would find is $W_1(r) = 0 \cdot W_2(r) + 0 + \epsilon$ specifically because $W_1$ and $W_2$ are independent and $W_1$ is mean zero.  So the residual is $\epsilon = W_1(r)$.

Comment: Many thanks for the comment: but this is continuous time regression where least squares spuriously yields a relationship. Note that expectation of $a$ is zero.